# Update a table column, then the other column with updated value of the former. MySQL / PostgreSQL differ

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, multiple-columns

```
create table test (
    id serial primary key,
    c1 int,
    c2 int
);

insert into test (c1,c2) values (1,1);

 -- here (id, c1, c2) = (1, 1, 1)

update test set c1=2, c2=c1+2;

SELECT * FROM  test ;
```

MySQL gives (1,2,4), Postgres gives (1,2,3).

I would like PostgreSQL to behave like MySQL, to work with updated value and not original one. Is it possible? Otherwise, if I have indexes on the column and do two updates instead of one, then I have unnecessary UPDATE = DELETE + INSERT (for PostgreSQL), and double the work. In particular case, I actually have to do 4 updates instead of one :(. Doing addition is easy outside SQL, but I have SQL related function instead.

N.B. As far as I remember, UPDATE = DELETE + INSERT may not be the case for numeric types, or is it if they have indexes? For varchars it is always true.

Comment: Since you're assigning a value to c1 why not do `c1 = 2, c2=2+2`?

Comment: Because, like I wrote, this is just example, in reality I use SQL function in the place instead of addition. I could do this: c1=f(c1), c2 = f2(f(c1)), write redundantly things.. but wondering if there is better solution.

Comment: Nice question. Can not find the standard behavior for SQL about UPDATE (googling for `SQL standard update source`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres is right.  According to the MySQL documentation:

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the
>   current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result
>   is that col1 and col2 have the same value. **This behavior differs from
>   standard SQL.**
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

I don't think you should ask for Postgres to be broken.

The logic that Postgres (and ANSI) use is simple. In an update statement, the values on the left of the `SET` refer to the *new* record; the values on the right refer to the *old* record.  The ordering of the assignments is not important.

MySQL has different rules.

In Postgres, you *could* do something like this:

```
update test
    set c1 = t1.new_c1, c2 = new_c1 + 2
    from (select t1.*, 2 as new_c1
          from test t1
         ) t1
    where test.id = t1.id;
```

Obviously, for a simple constant this is overkill, but for a complex expression it might make sense.  Also, because the `JOIN` is on primary keys, there is little impact on performance.

Comment: I've seen these types of SQLs before I discovered this MySQL/PostgreSQL difference, and suspected there may be a reason for their use :)